# Is there any level requirement to purchase the Hydra?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'd rather not have to grind or play for hours in order to get an attack aircraft in GTA Online. I read on GTA wiki that the Hydra unlocks after the EMP in the Humane Labs Raid.

Are there any level requirements needed to complete the Humane Labs Raid, to complete the two pre-requisite heists (Fleeca and Prison Break), or to purchase the Hydra from Warstock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no level requirement to purchase Hydra, all you need is to complete Humane Raid - EMP mission and save up mere $3,000,000.
There is no level requirement to join any heist and you don't even need to do the prerequisite heists, if someone else is hosting it.